# Lifting an automorphism to the universal covering space..

Tags: covering-spaces

Let $X$ be a manifold and $Y$ be its universal covering. Is it true that any $\phi \in \mathrm{Aut}(X)$ can be lifted to $\overline{\phi}\in \mathrm{Aut}(Y)$?

Answer (score 4):

In general, if you have a map $f \colon X \to X'$, then it lifts to the universal covers $\tilde f \colon Y \to Y'$, since the composition $f \circ p \colon Y \to X'$ satisfies the condition in Idan's answer. To show that in your case, the map is in $\mathrm{Aut}(Y)$, check that this lifting behaves well with composition and identity.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 1):

Generally, if p is the cover map, the a function $f:Z\rightarrow X$ can be lifted iff $f_*:\pi_1(Z)\rightarrow\pi_1(X): f_*(\varphi)=f\circ\varphi$ 
satisfies $f_*(\pi_1(Z))\le p_*(\pi_1(Y))$. The universal covering has a trivial fundamental group, so unless $f_*(\pi_1(Z))$ is trivial, it doesn't seem like we can lift the map.

Comment: Isn't $p_{*}(\pi_{1}(Y))$ trivial in your answer?

Comment: @M.K. yes, but so is $f_\ast(\pi_1(Z))$.

Comment: I may misunderstand something. We are interested in the case $Z=X$ and $f \in \mathrm{Aut}(X)$. To me the condition looks like $\pi_1(X) \le p_*(\pi_1(Y))=\{0\}$.

Comment: It is, my mistake...

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the point.